# How to access an attribute into a struct from a void pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am given a task which i can't see what a function does in detail but i only know what id does generally.

So i have a function, let's call it "get_button", and in the documentation i know that "it returns a pointer to the button struct". I know the button struct, it's something like:

```
struct button{
    int size;
    char title;
    short keyID;
};
```

The function is something like:

```
void * get_button(int ID, int group)
```

But i can't know what it does.

Now i want to know the title, but playing with the complier i got that i have a void pointer in return. So how i am supposed to use this void pointer? ASAIK i have to use a static_cast to give a reference to it, but in this case is a struct; moreover i can't really understand what casting means and how to make the compiler know that i want a certain struct.

This is a particular case where i need to know how to get a parameter into a struct from a void pointer. I don't know if i should use a static_cast or whatever (so i can't understand the reference to it). Neither i need to know how to use propery a void pointer in this case! I just need to know how i can access the attribute in the struct.
I've seen the other answers here and there but i couldn't find something valuable for this case.

Comment: A void pointer is just a pointer that doesn't specify the type of what it points to. If you know for sure that it's actually pointing to a certain structure, you can cast it to a pointer to that structure (using `static_cast` or a plain C-style cast) and then use it normally. However, if you are using a library that is giving you void pointers, maybe it's providing you an "opaque handle" on purpose, and you are supposed to pass it to the relevant library functions to actually work with it. Some more detail about the library you are using and/or the context could help us to give relevant advice

Comment: I just know the function call, but i can't know whe function istructions. I am told that "it returns a pointer to the struct", not other things. I am working with an embedded machine which has previously been programmed with C and only recently with c++. I just know the button struct, defined into a key.h library (included in the program ofc) that is something like the thing i wrote. I have no more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i can't really understand what casting means

You answer yourself in your next question:

> how to make the compiler know that i want a certain struct.

That's exactly it. Casting means that you tell the compiler, that the object has a specific type.

> This is a particular case where i need to know how to get a parameter into a struct from a void pointer.

First, cast the void pointer into the pointer type of the object that it points to: `*button`. Then you can access the attribute normally, using the `operator->` on the pointer of correct type.

> I don't know if i should use a static_cast or whatever

When casting a void pointer to another pointer type, you should indeed use `static_cast`.

```
void* void_pointer = get_button(ID, group); // get the pointer
button* button_pointer = static_cast<button*>(void_pointer); // cast to the type of the pointed object
int size = button_pointer->size; // access the attribute through the pointer
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i can try something else now. But the thing i can't understand in this case is: why the architect didin't use a return the struct pointer at first? He knew that the only possible cast would have been to that particular struct.

Comment: @MarkWuji you'll need to ask the architect for a definite answer. Are you sure that's the only possible cast? Maybe the function can return pointers to other types of objects as well.

Comment: Yes it is. Documentation tells "This function returns the address of the button struct specified with the ID". Problem is, i can't ask the architect, he's not working anymore with my company. I am doing the dirty job :)
Anyway i will try with this solution, seems fine, but it just did a system fault on my machine :) Thank you in advice.

Comment: @MarkWuji well, given that documentation, could there be *other* button structs, besides `button`? Maybe there isn't, but there might have been in future? If the function only returns pointers to single type of objects, and it's not planned to ever return anything else, then it doesn't make any sense to return a void pointer.

Comment: I am still having troubles with my program, but your answer is actually correct; thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a plain C old style cast with your struct to a void pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct button{
    int size;
    char title;
    short keyID;
};

int main()
{
    button b;
    b.size  = 1;
    b.title = 'c';
    b.keyID = 2;
    void *p = &b;
    button *a = (button *)p;
    std::cout << a->size << std::endl;
    std::cout << a->title << std::endl;
    std::cout << a->keyID << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is basically an address of where in memory something is, in your case a button struct.
That address doesn't change when the type of the pointer is changed to void*, so if your library providing the get_button function guarantees that the returned pointer will in fact point to a valid button struct, you can safely cast it back to a button* in order to use it (think of it as giving the compiler some extra information).

You'd go about it as follows:

```
void *what_is_returned = get_button();
button *the_button = static_cast<button *>(what_is_returned);
char the_character_you_want = the_button->title;
```

The -> operator means "dereference and access member", it's a shorthand for dereferencing what the left hand side variable contains (looking up the address, like in *the_button) and then accessing the member (like in (*the_button).title), effectively adding the offset of the title member within the button struct to the button's address and fetching the char from there.